# Charting in R - Bar chart and Line chart

Tags: r

I am an excel user and trying to use R now to replicate the work in excel. My dataset is as below:

`Time        Utilisation          ExpensedFTE
1/04/2019     0.7625                 0.8
1/03/2019     0.813                  0.923

1/02/2019     0.88                   0.8
1/06/2019     1                      1
1/01/2019     0.585714286            1`

I am trying to create a line chart with time line to show the pattern in Utilisation and expensed FTE. I can create a bar chart with one variable only (either Utilisation or ExpensedFTE) using the code below. I cannot create a bar chart with both the variables.

`ggplot(FindataCOmp,aes(x=Time,y=Count_of_FTE_Actual))+geom_bar(stat='identity')`

I also failed to create a line chart with single or multiple variable.

Can I please get some help?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a line chart, you can use `geom_line()` instead of `geom_bar()`. Also, for the plot you are trying to create, it's usually good to put the data into long format before plotting. Here's an example with the data you've provided:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Time = c("1/04/2019", "1/03/2019", "1/02/2019", "1/06/2019", "1/01/2019"),
                 Utilisation = c(0.7625, 0.813, 0.88, 1, 0.585714286),
                 ExpensedFTE = c(0.8, 0.923, 0.8, 1, 1))

df %>%
  gather(group, value, Utilisation:ExpensedFTE) -> graph_data

ggplot(graph_data, aes(x = Time, y = value, group = group)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = group))
```

[image]